# Spring Boot - How to add custom controller logic before user accesses static files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project, where some static contents are served from the src/main/resources/static directory.

My goal is that whenever a user tries to access static contents that end with a certain suffix (e.g. ".xlsx"), the request is intercepted and I check to see if the user has the right permission using Spring AOP, and reject the request if necessary. I've got the AOP part working in other scenarios, but not in this scenario yet.

Currently I've tried something like the following, but the method isn't being invoked upon accessing a file of ".xlsx" suffix:

```
@RequestMapping("/*.xlsx")
public void checkPermission() {

}
```

Can this be done without using Spring Security? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the same question already answered .Please refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446115/spring-boot-how-to-add-interceptors-to-static-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Filter interface? much more available.

LINK: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html

Using this you can easily parse the request before even it reaches the controller and add you business logic/validation to it.